# This code is not running on python file, but says it runs as correct hackerran

Tags: python-3.x, program-entry-point

This code runs in HackerRank exercises but I can not run it in spyder can someone please say what is the problem.
Thank you

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())

    a1= a // b
    a2 = a /b

    print(a1)
    print(a2)
```

Comment: What is HackerRank?  What is spyder?

Comment: Also, it should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: @RocketHazmat HackerRank is a website for coding Practice where it gives exercises to practice. Anaconda Spyder is an application you install to run code such as python. Yes, even with that I can not run it like the compiler won't ask me for user input.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I had problem writting  the codes here that's why I deleted the ' '

Comment: I even tried the code on repl.it wont work

Comment: I tried it at https://tio.run and it works for me: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxDoAgEAR7XnEdUBEwNia85QKJxis4icHC1yNCY9xudmfzXfaDp1ppA0QOaUUE70EipkCMKBcBLQE8EBdFnK@itO5l/JdDtb7pxkAc6KBzHGs@30ew@ktO12qdmB8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @RocketHazmat still it does not work on myside. does not ask me for input

Answer (score 1):

It's `if __name__ == "__main__":`, not `if __name__ == __main__:`